# Css: align image and select with overflow

Tags: css, overflow

I have the following html code :

```
<div>
    <img src="..." />
    <select> ... </select>
<div>
```

and the following css :

```
div { 
    width: 100px;
    height: 32px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
img { width: 32px }
select { 
    width: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

I need to vertical align the image and the select field. The fact that the select field will be in overflow is normal. The goal is to show the part of the select field that is not in overflow next to my image.

Currently, the select field is below the image.

I'm no sure if my explanation is clear, so ask more details if you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to nest two divs: An outer one with "overflow:hidden;", and an inner one that is wide enough to contain the two elements:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="inner">
        <img />
        <select></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.wrap {
    width:100px;
    height:32px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
div.inner {
   width:200px;
}
img {width: 32px;}
select {width: 150px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
div { 
    width: 100px;
    height: 32px;
    overflow: hidden;


}
img { width: 32px 
float:left;}
select { 
    width: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it does not work. The select field is still below the image

Comment: please increase the div width or decrease the select tag width and float left/right